# davfs2 package not found on CENTOS 7.3 x86_64

Tags: centos, yum, webdav

I'm having some issues trying to install davfs2 on my CentOS server, I run

```
 yum install davfs2
```

but I get this:

```
 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, priorities, universal-hooks
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
  * EA4: 91.197.228.252
  * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 91.197.228.252
  * base: centos.quelquesmots.fr
  * centosplus: centos.mirror.fr.planethoster.net
  * extras: centos.quelquesmots.fr
  * rpmforge: mirrors.ircam.fr
   * updates: centos.quelquesmots.fr
  Nothing to do
```

Not sure but maybe I need add more mirrors to my distro, if it's not possible install davfs2 I'd like to know other alternative for mount webdav routes as folder in CentOS, cadaver is a webdav client but I can't mount folders with it...

thank you guys, have a nice day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to enable the EPEL repo in order to install that package:

```
yum -y install epel-release
yum -y install davfs2
```

After you're done installing the required packages please disable the epel repo since you are on a cPanel server and this additional repo, at some point might break some package dependencies when cPanel/WHM nightly update is running.

To disable the EPEL repo you can edit **/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo** file and replace **enabled=1** with **enabled=0**